# Enable Remote Docker API on Windows Host - Adding daemon.json breaks docker

Tags: docker

We currently have a Windows server and a Linux server that acts as our docker hosts for various containers. I would like to set up Portainer on my local machine and add Server's endpoints. I have manage to get the Linux one work by changing the `ExecStart` to include the tcp address and this is working as expected.

However when it comes to adding the tcp host to the Windows server Docker breaks. Everywhere I read suggest to add a `daemon.json` file at `/ProgramData/Docker/Config`. When I add this file and try to restart docker, it fails to restart.

**daemon.json**

```
{
    "hosts":["tcp://172.16.0.52:2375"]
}
```

**Docker Version:**

```
Version: 19.03.5
API version: 1.40
Go version: go1.12.12
Git commit: 2ee0c57608
Build: 11/13/2019 08:00:16
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: false
```

Comment: **You are opening a major security hole.**  Anyone who can reach that port 2375 can trivially root the system, with no security checks at all.  Turn that option off **now**, and use some other way to remotely administer the system.

Comment: There is the option to add TLS certs which I was planning to add once I managed to get it all working as expected.